# Elasticsearch How Coordinating node works?

Tags: elasticsearch

I'm using Elsaticsearch Cluster(7.7 OSS Version).

I'm running total 5 nodes, 2 for coordinating nodes and 3 for master & data nodes.

I read Elasticsearch Node Role Guide(https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/modules-node.html#coordinating-node)
and it's telling that "Every node is implicitly a coordinating node"

And I got confused, the guide means my master & data nodes can be also Coordinating node too and the seperation of coordinating nodes and master & data nodes becomes useless.

If the coordinating nodes role is empty, then the coordinating nodes got the higher priority for processing search requests or bulk-indexing?

My Coordinating node's yml file is like this

```
node.master: false
node.data: false
node.ingest: false
```

When I call _cat/nodes api, my coordinating node actually has the role 'remote_client_cluster'
Is my coordinating nodes actually works as coordinating nodes? or works as remote_client_cluster node?

[image]

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It's true that all nodes are coordinating nodes by nature, which means they can handle user requests if they receive one. Your two coordinating nodes are actually [**coordinating-only** nodes](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/7.7/modules-node.html#coordinating-only-node), which means that all they can do is act as load balancer nodes to dispatch user requests to data nodes and gather node responses before sending them back to the client.

When you introduce coordinating-only nodes, the idea is to direct all user traffic to those nodes, whether the traffic comes from your clients, Logstash, Kibana, or any other application that needs to interact with Elasticsearch. Those coordinating-only nodes will know the cluster state, and thus, where to route the search and indexing traffic. They act like smart load balancers.

Your coordinating-only node, to be truly coordinating only, must have the following configuration:

```
node.data: false 
node.ingest: false 
node.master: false 
node.ml: false 
node.remote_cluster_client: false 
node.transform: false 
node.voting_only: false
```

So to sum up:

- Your two coordinating nodes will handle and manage the user traffic like a load balancer in front of your cluster
- Your master nodes will do their master-ish work
- Your data nodes will do their data-ish work

Comment: Thanks for your reploy! I understand the coordinating node now.
If I didn't write node.remote_cluster_client:false in the coordinating node, 
it seems still works as coordinating nodes(my logstash output is two coordinating nodes ip). Does it right?